# How to delete a file using command batch script for a particular starts-with characters?

Tags: batch-file, command, command-prompt

Here is my requirement

This is my folder structure

[image]

I need to delete `com.team.automation` jar file using command batch script.

I have to delete all the files which starts-with `com.team.automation` name

Here is the batch script snippet which I used for delete

```
SET TEST=com.team.automation?
DEL %TEST%
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this one??

Comment: You need to learn the syntax for [batch wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html). In batch, `?` stands for one or zero characters, and `*` stands for any character(s). I guess you should be using `*` instead.

Comment: Then you'd be wise to open up a Command Prompt window, and enter `del /?`, _or `erase /?`_, to read the usage information for the command you're running.